# enter key produces " '> " in MYSQL Console

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

In the MYSQL Console, I was attempting to add multiple values to a table and in an effort to start a new line, I selected shift+enter which produced `'>`. Now, every time I hit enter, I get `'>` rather than inserting  my values or really being able to do anything now. How do I stop this?

[image]

Comment: It means that your string literal isn't closed. It's waiting for the closing single quote.

Comment: You forgot to close a quote, that's what it means.

Comment: Try typing `\c` (backslash-c) to clear the mysql input line.

Comment: @Mox Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have opened a quote `'` and did not closed it. Add another quote `'` to close the opened one, add a semicolon `;` to end the command and hit enter to execute it (you maybe get a syntax error, it the opened quote must be closed earlier).